# Auto size in @ngx-gallery/lightbox

Tags: angular, image-gallery

I trie to make my post photos div with autosize photos in one div. Such here

[image]

Now I have this.

[image]

The first screen from 'Angular2 Image Gallery'. I cant use it on Angular 8. If you advice me the npm where I can make auto size in div all photos it will be great. Or advice me how to make it in @ngx-gallery/lightbox. Thanks

Comment: just as a start I would recommend you to do `img {
  width: auto;
  height: 70px;
}`

Comment: well yes just as a start doesn't solve the whole problem but it will be better than the result you have I think you have done the invert you add a fixed witdth with height auto that's the opposite if you want to get closer to the first example you've posted

Comment: I didnt now how I dont think about it. It is work. Give an answer and I click such a right